# need finite 'xlim' values using reactive function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a Linear regression Shiny app with a custom file input. I have a problem with the reactive function in Server.R. The reactive function *data* returns a data frame called *qvdata*. When *data()* is called in renderPlot and I plot from the *qvdata* I get the following error:
"Error in plot.window(...):need finite 'xlim' values". When I do not use the reactive function and do the calculations in renderPlot the error does not occur. Why is this? I want later to be able to call this data reactive function in other render functions to prevent repetition in the code.

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
data<-reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
    #takes in data (In my case .dat file)
    qvdata=read.table(inFile$datapath)
    names(qvdata)=c("H","Q")
    qvdata$Hlog=log(qvdata[,1])
    qvdata$Qlog=log(qvdata[,2])
    xbar=mean(qvdata$Hlog)
    ybar=mean(qvdata$Qlog)
    xdif=qvdata$Hlog-xbar
    ydif=qvdata$Qlog-ybar
    Sxy=sum(xdif*ydif)
    Sxx=sum(xdif*xdif)
    #point estimates of alfa and beta
    qvdata$b=Sxy/Sxx
    qvdata$a=ybar-qvdata$b*xbar
    qvdata
})

output$contents <- renderPlot({
    qvdata=data()
    t=seq(0,2,0.01)
    abline=qvdata$a+qvdata$b*t
    plot(qvdata$Hlog,qvdata$Qlog,type="p",pch=20,col="red")
    lines(t,abline,col="black")
})
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel('Linear regression'),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput('file1', 'Choose file')   
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('contents')

        )
    )
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` function runs the first time when your shiny app starts. Because the input file is missing it will return `NULL`. But Your plotting function doesn't test its input and is equivalent to `plot(NULL)` in this case. If you test for an input `!is.null()` it should work:

```
output$contents <- renderPlot({
    qvdata=data()
    if (!is.null(qvdata)) {
      t=seq(0,2,0.01)
      abline=qvdata$a+qvdata$b*t
      plot(qvdata$Hlog,qvdata$Qlog,type="p",pch=20,col="red")
      lines(t,abline,col="black")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to standard date formate worked for me.

Use `as.POSIXct()`